# How to generate random points inside a rectangle with Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability

How to generate $N$ random points inside a rectangle of side $L\times L$ with a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Isn't the support of a Gaussian measure the entire plane?

Comment: Yep. (Hey NCMathSadist---NCSSM '86 right here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your requirements are contradictory. A Gaussian distribution has infinite extent, so once you limit yourself to an $L\times L$ rectangle, it can no longer be a Gaussian distribution.

However, one thing you can do is generate points using a raw Gaussian distribution and simply *discard* those that fall outside of the $L\times L$ rectangle. The points that remain will be distributed according to a truncated Gaussian distribution.

If you wish to edit your question to provide more specifics on what you're looking to do, I will edit my answer to suit.

EDIT: Here is some example MATLAB code to generate $N$ points with mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma$ inside a rectangle of size $L\times L$. No error checking is performed!

```
function ans = randn_rect( N, sigma, L )
ans = zeros(0,2);
while size(ans,1) < N,
   pts = sigma * randn( ceil(1.25*(N-size(ans,1))), 2 );
   pts = pts(all(abs(pts)<L/2,2),:);
   ans = [ ans ; pts ];
end
ans = ans(1:N,:);
```

Comment: I just have a rectangle and N points, and I want to deploy those points inside a rectangles with a Gaussian distribution, is this not sufficient?

Comment: If the points have a true Gaussian distribution, then they cannot be contained within a rectangle. The Gaussian distribution has infinite extent. Now, they could have a *truncated* Gaussian distribution, which is what I have described in my answer here. Are you asking how to write the code? In what language?

Comment: You mean that if I use truncated Gaussian distribution, I will have no guarantee that all points will be included inside a rectangle?

Comment: If you use a *truncated* Gaussian distribution, sure. But you have to do the truncation yourself, which is my point. A *true* Gaussian distribution can make no such guarantees.

Comment: In this case which form will include all the points, circle?

Comment: I am using python language

Comment: "In this case which form will include all the points, circle?" I do not know what this means. Again: if you want a *true* Gaussian distribution, there is *no rectangle or circle or any other volume* that is guaranteed to contain them all. You must deliberately discard the points that fall outside of your desired extent. And once you commit to doing that, you can pick whatever extent you want: a rectangle, circle, whatever.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: I'm sorry my Python is too rusty to just bang out an equivalent NumPy implementation above.

Comment: Is it possible to get only the algorithm of how to generate the $X,Y$ coordinates of each point?

Comment: I have never worked with Matlab, if you could give me a python code I will be grateful.

Comment: @sys: if you want code examples, try asking on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). They have quite a few Python experts there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm done programming here. I'd take Ilmari's suggestion.